# I need to add static json object to database with column name wise how can i add that json fie in my project

Tags: objectmapper

I have json scratch and i need to insert that json into database table how can add that scratch json into database

```
{
  name:'John',
  phone:'98255874',
  address:'Nepal',
  profile:'../../assets/images/bg.jpg',
  speacialon:'Heart',
  description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum aliquid sit ullam, aperiam libero tempore amet voluptates ex temporibus error expedita incidunt dicta eius odit animi, eos quo, perspiciatis rerum?'
},
```

Comment: In which database